# x86 Assembler: shl and other instructions

Tags: x86, assembly

I'm trying to understand some assembler code inside a loop. The loop runs from 1 to 255 and does the following inside the loop:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
shl    eax,0x2
add    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
mov    DWORD PTR [eax],0x0
```

Here the `DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]` refers to the number going from 1 to 255.

Can someone figure out what is going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just zeroing an array apparently:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4] ; load index
shl    eax,0x2                 ; multiply index by 4 to get byte offset
add    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8] ; add byte offset to array base address
mov    DWORD PTR [eax],0x0     ; zero value at array[index]
```

Comment: Great, of course! Thanks. Been looking at it for a while, but just couldn't see it.

Comment: why don't just use LEA for address calculation?